# VBA empty string for insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Here is the situation:
There's a SQL Server database with a Microsoft Access front end.  There is a table in the SQL Server database with a column called PackID which is defined as VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL (it has to be NOT NULL because it's part of a composite primary key for this table).  Empty strings are legitimate in the PackID column.  In fact, they occur quite often.  When the user enters data in the UI for this table, and tabs through the PackID field, an error message appears: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PackID'; column does not allow nulls.  INSERT fails."

Things that have been tried that do not work:

1. adding a default constraint on this column in the SQL Server database with a value of '' - apparently the default is only used if the column is omitted from the INSERT statement
2. setting the Default Value of the PackID field in Access to "" - it behaves as though "" is a NULL
3. calling the following VBA code when user moves off row in UI (Lost Focus event)

   ```
   If IsNull(PackID.Value) Then
      PackID.Value = ""
   End If
   ```

Does anyone know how to force an empty string in Access so it's interpreted as an empty string for SQL Server and not a NULL?

Comment: Does the line `IsNull(ComponentPackID.Value)` return True?

Comment: It's probably a thing in Access to make your life "easier" to send NULLs for a blank string, because in the bad old VBA days, there weren't good ways to deal with NULL values. It is hacky but how about a single space, then trim everything back on its way in?

Comment: Yes, it does return True.

Comment: Do you have any control over the SQL server? Is it an option to drop a trigger in there, to convert NULLs to empty strings before insert? (Note: I haven't tested this, but if it isn't an option, then there's no point in seeing if it works.)

Comment: Sadly, no.  This is to be solved on the UI side.

Comment: or if an integer a sentinel value like -1?

Comment: Jeremy - Can you elaborate on where to perform the trim?  I attempted this approach in VBA using the Lost Focus event but it still interprets the trimmed space as NULL.

Comment: In your IF statement above change the empty string to " ".

Comment: But `LostFocus` of what element?  Do you mean TextBox.OnLostFocus? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193542.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Try using `Form_BeforeUpdate`...

Comment: @Jeremy: Yep, did that.  Wondering where to perform the TRIM operation though.

Comment: @VDohnal: Form_LostFocus.  Also tried Form_BeforeUpdate with no success.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful if you update how you link SQL tables (suppose not adp project) - SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver?

Comment: Check this, but no help: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/892369-how-make-access-use-empty-string-instead-null

Comment: @knot22 you would trim in and sql statement that is selecting from that field, or simply check for a space in your other logic. Depending on your usage of the field, you may not need to trim it.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-null-value-conflicts-between-access-and-sql-server/ this article suggests using the `Nz()` function... I've not got a setup like yours to test it out, but it's worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Default Value in the text box Properties for PackID in Access to this

```sql
=" "
```

worked.  The space between the double quotes is very important.  Leaving the space out causes the insert to fail.  In SQL Server LEN(PackID) returns 0.  For instance:

```sql
SELECT LEN(''), LEN(' ');
```

both return 0.  It appears as though SQL Server treats both of these as empty strings.

Comment: So for me it is clear: never create app in Access with SQL Server database... Sadly they have dropped ADP support in Access 2013.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to this problem (no Default Value in text box Properties for PackID).

```vba
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(PackID.Value) Or PackID.Value = "" Then
        PackID.Value = " "
    End If
End Sub
```

This still uses the concept of passing SQL Server " " (read this as quote space quote) as the field's value.  On the UI side, this is an alternative to setting a default value for the field.